# How to predict the volume and dimensions after shrinkage ?

Tags: thermodynamics

I have only the shrinkage allowances of the material together with the initial dimensions, as you can see in the photo. 
What would be the dimensions after cooling this mould? 
I have no information about the possible temperature gradient, what i know is, this mould is filled with molten cast iron and it then cooled too room temperature. [image]

Comment: Do you at least know what material it is?

Comment: @ChesterMiller, Cast Iron, i know exactly the shrinkage allowances, and composition.

Comment: Is the molten iron still inside when the mold is cooled?  Is the mold constrained in any way?

Comment: @ChesterMiller, The point is to use this machine elements later, in a room temperature, but i need first to over dimension the mould, so when it forms a solid, its dimensions perfectly matches the housing and other elements in the machine.

Comment: Well, if the mold is unconstrained, the thermal expansion will be described in terms of the coefficient of linear expansion for all the dimensions.  The final shape will be geometrically similar to the initial shape.